# Where is the source code of python generator send?

Tags: python, generator, send

## Question

Please help pin-point the Python source code that implements the generator send part. I suppose somewhere in github [This is Python version 3.8.7rc1](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.8) but not familiar with how the repository is organized.

## Background

Having difficulty with what PEP 342 and documentation regarding the generator send(value). Hence trying to find out how it is implemented to understand.

- `there is no yield expression to receive a value when the generator has just been created`
- `The value argument becomes the result of the **current yield expression**. The send() method returns the **next value yielded by the generator`

[Specification: Sending Values into Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#specification-sending-values-into-generators)

> Because generator-iterators begin execution at the top of the
> generator's function body, **there is no yield expression to receive a
> value** when the generator has just been created. Therefore, calling
> send() with a non-None argument is prohibited when the generator
> iterator has just started, and a TypeError is raised if this occurs
> (presumably due to a logic error of some kind). Thus, before you can
> communicate with a coroutine you must first call next() or send(None)
> to advance its execution to the first yield expression.

[generator.send(value)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send)

> Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function.
> The value argument becomes the result of the **current yield expression**.
> The send() method returns the **next value yielded by the generator**, or
> raises StopIteration if the generator exits without yielding another
> value. When send() is called to start the generator, it must be called
> with None as the argument, because there is no yield expression that
> could receive the value.

I suppose `yield` would be like a UNIX system call moving into a routine, inside which stack frame and execution pointer are saved and the generator co-routine is suspended. I think when save(value) is called, some tricks happen there and those are regarding the cryptic parts in the documents.

Although `sent_value = (yield value)` is one line statement, the blocking and resuming both happens in the same line, I think. The execution does not resume after the `yield` but within it, hence would like to know how block/resume are implemented. Also I believe `next(generator) is the same with generator.send(None)` and would like to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/463c7d3d149283814d879a9bb8411af64e656c8e/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L322) for class Generator, also look for [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ace3f9a0ce7b9fe8ae757fdd614f1e7a171f92b0/Objects/genobject.c) file, is a complete implementation of generators on C inside Python